# i have a function in angularjs that will total the amount but, it wont accept two decimal places

Tags: angularjs

I have a code here to sum or total the value but i want it to display as with 2 decimal places. I just copy the code i have used so i don't have an idea of this codes here.. i'm just learning. i want some help :)

here's the code

```
$scope.totalPrice = function(){
            var total = 0;
            for(count=0;count<$scope.data.length;count++){
                total += parseInt($scope.data[count].total_amount,10);
            }
            return total;
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: "integers" don't have decimal places...

Having obtained a number with decimal places, you'll probably want to use `total.toFixed(2)` to turn it into a string with the desired precision.

Comment: so the parseInt is the problem here? what should i use there?

Comment: you should use `parseFloat`

Comment: thanks! :D i got it now :) it's now display with 2 decimal places :)

Comment: sorry, but i'm having some difficulties in understanding haha, what is the difference in having toFixed(2) and not having it?

Comment: If you don't have it, then due to the way computers do arithmetic you might get sums that get displayed as e.g. 4.20000000000000017764 (instead of "4.20")

Comment: ahh ok, but even if i didn't add toFixed here is it displays with 2 decimals only. why?

Comment: it depends on the number - some decimal numbers (e.g. 3.5, 3.75) can be exactly represented in binary, some can't.

Comment: ahh because here in my database it is an exact decimal numbers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)